# Is it a bad idea to add a period to a .Net solution file?

Tags: .net, build-process, installation, naming-conventions, projects-and-solutions

If I was using a "[Partitioned Single Solution](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms998208.aspx)" strategy to build my .Net projects and solutions, could anyone comment on, or share any experiences about why it would be a bad idea to include dot notation in my solution names as such...

master.sln
    master.sub.sln

...also let me know if you think it's a good idea? Please note that I'm not looking for someone to ask me "why don't you just use underscores or dashes". I'm just curious about any specific reasons why you wouldn't want to use periods.

Thanks,
-Matt

Comment: I've never tried it, but I don't see it causing a problem.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

No reason not to use dots.  I use them all the time, particularly since our company names all projects/solutions like this:

Solutions:
CompanyName.DepartmentName.Application

Projects:
CompanyName.DepartmentName.Application.ProjectName

Comment: Same here. It's rather unusual that my solution files do *not* contain periods.

Answer (score 2):

I think it's perfectly acceptable and have used periods many times. Just be consistent and harness your OCD.

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't do it because I'd find it confusing.  The solutions should be capturing specific subsystems within your overall application architecture, so I would name the solutions after those subsystems.  The hierarchical data is something that I would expect in the project names for the various modules.

If you have a hierarchy for solutions *and* a hierarchy for projects, that'd be confusing.  Especially if they're different hierarchies.

Comment: I will note that this *is* a subjective point of view.  I won't say that you're *wrong* because you aren't, I don't believe that there's an objectively "right" way.  I'm just saying that I wouldn't do it that way for this reason.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see a "problem" using dots in solution file name. I did use them in the past as well. However these days, I just use short solution file names without any dots. I find it easier to read and locate, especially from recent projects list.

I do indeed use dots for project files for organizing hierarchy.

I guess it's just a personal preference thing for solution file names.